# Вывод pandas в красивом табличном виде с помощью tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Сейчас вывожу массив pandas в окно (tkinter), ячейки идентифицируются нормально, но выводится это не очень красиво и не полностью. Хочу вывести данные таблицей с прокруткой, чтобы все можно было просмотреть.

```
from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('Fanera_y.txt',  sep='   ', parse_dates=True)




window = Tk()

window.title("Таблица")


lbl = Label(window, text=data)

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import pandas as pd


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, text: pd.DataFrame = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text = text.columns.values
        self.parent = parent
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent, columns=self.text[1:])
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        for i, j in enumerate(self.text):
            self.tree.heading(f"#{i}", text=j)
        for i in range(len(text[self.text[0]])):
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=text[self.text[0]][i], values=list(map(lambda x: text[x][i], self.text[1:])))

        self.tree.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
    main = Main(text=data)
    main.mainloop()
```